# How to provide evidence of family allowance in visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am applying for a UK visitor visa and I indicated in the application that I receive money from my family. How can I prove this? The money is given in cash and there is no transfer evidence.

Answer (score 4):

1. Start depositing *all* of the cash into your bank account (open an account if you don't already have one) as you receive it
2. Wait 6 months before applying again
3. Show your account statements

The ECO reviewing your application needs to see hard evidence of your financial circumstances, and cash passed from one family member to another with no records doesn't cut it.

It's important to deposit all of the cash you receive so that this full amount is recorded on the bank statement. Obviously you'll need to be spending some of it, and you should then withdraw from the account as you need it.

Comment: What if I have to apply now? Any other evidence I can provide?

Comment: I do have an account and some cash deposited in it. But how can I prove the source of this cash?

Comment: @SaraChatila your earlier question indicated that you have already received a refusal which noted, among other issues, insufficient funds of your own. A new application with a sudden infusion of monies, with no proof of provenance, is quite risky and, if it fails, a second refusal would make it very unlikely you would be able to visit the UK anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

To disagree with brhans slightly, you can apply now but having no formal records of income means you are more likely to be refused.

That said, your overall circumstances might make a difference. For example, if you are young and still studying then it's not so bad that you have an allowance in cash.

Brhans advice is still correct though. If you don't have a really urgent reason to travel then it's better not to risk a refusal.